# Cannot modify variable value while debugging C code in VS Code with the Cortex Debug extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging

I am using STM32F4 and trying to debug C code using VS Code with [the Cortex Debug extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=marus25.cortex-debug). When I try to modify the value of a static variable, I am seeing the error below.

> Could not set variable: Variable object not found (from var-assign
> my_var 0x1388)

`my_var` is a `uint32_t`

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: what language is this? (C/C++?) and what VS Code extension are you using that contributes the debug adapter?

Comment: Its C . I am using Cortex debug

Comment: if you don't see an existing matching issue ticket (see https://github.com/Marus/cortex-debug/issues?q=is%3Aissue+static+variable), I'd suggest to raise an issue ticket. If you do find or create one, please ping me here with a link to it.

Comment: Seems like there is a ticket already and its been resolved . I upgraded to a new version (1.83) and I dont see the problem anymore . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem was partially solved by updating VS Code to [version 1.83](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_83). I'd like to elaborate, but the cause of the issue is not known by me or the asker of the question. Apparently there are still some issues, which are being tracked by https://github.com/Marus/cortex-debug/issues/947, but which should be fixed by [commit `5a2effed`](https://github.com/Marus/cortex-debug/commit/5a2effedf4311dacf443180106868478456a1d92).

Comment: I am not sure what is happening. I cannot edit values always even with 1.83. Anyways I created a ticket in github

Comment: @pranathi please comment here with the link to your issue ticket. Is it in https://github.com/Marus/cortex-debug/issues ?

Comment: https://github.com/Marus/cortex-debug/issues/947
Yes its under the same repo'